# How to manage SqlConnection in C# for high frequency transaction?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, database-connection, connection-pooling

I have an application that connect to a SQL Server database with high frequency. Inside this service, there are many scheduled tasks that run every second, and each time I'm executing some query.

I don't understand which solution is better in this condition.

- Opening a single `SqlConnection` and keeping it open while application is running and execute all query with that connection
- Each time I want to execute query, opening a new connection and after query execution, close the connection (does this solution suitable for so many scheduled task that runs every 1 second?)

I tried second solution, but is there any better choice?

How do ORMs like EF manage connections?

[image: Background Service Manager]

As you see i have many service. I cant change interval and the interval is important for me. but the code makes so many calls and im following a better way manage connection over database. Also I'm making connection with `Using Statement`.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: Define "better". At the moment this reads like you could be asking for opinions, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: What do you mean by a "resource problem" What do you mean by others can't work in the application? This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: "Currently I have a resource problem in SQL Server" It seems this is the problem you are trying to solve. Please post more information and perhaps we can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are already opening/closing your SQL connections in either a "using" statement or explicitly in your code ( try/catch/finally ). If so you are already making use of connection pooling as it is enabled in ADO.Net by default ("By default, connection pooling is enabled in ADO.NET").

Therefore I don't think that your problem is so much a connection/resource problem as it is a database concurrency issue. I assume it to be either 1 of 2 issues :

1. Your code is making so many calls to the SQL server that it is exhausting all the available connections and nobody else can get one
2. Your code is locking tables in SQL that is causing other code/applications to timeout

If it is case 1, try and redesign your code to be "less chatty" to the database. Instead of making several inserts/updates per second, perhaps buffer the changes and make a single insert/update every 3-5 seconds in batch mode ( obvs if possible ). Or maybe your SQL statements are taking longer than 1 second to execute and you are calling them every second causing in a backlog scenario?

If it is case 2, try and redesign the SQL tables in such a way that the "reading" applications are not influenced by the "writing" application. Normally this involves a service that periodically writes aggregated data to a read-only table for viewing or at very least adding a "WITH(NOLOCK)" hint to the select clauses to allow dirty reads ( i.e. it wont lock the table to read, but may result in slightly out of date dataset i.e. eventual consistency )

Good luck

Comment: As i described more on question, my problem is first one and i cant change execution interval.
I'm following a better way to manage connection

Comment: Does your application/s ever run out of connections? 
"The connection pool has been exhausted"
I think your problem is you have many applications, each of which is using the "default" 100 connection pool size. ( 20 app X 100 connections = 2000 SQL Connections ). 
Maybe try and limit your connection pools to a smaller size :

"server=localhost;database=???;uid=??;pwd=???;Max Pool Size=30;"

Comment: The `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint should *almost* never be used, and definitely should never be recommended. There are much better alternatives such as `SNAPSHOT` isolation or `RCSI`, or architecture redesign. OP can also solve case #1, more simply, by opening just a single connection to the database, as his question proposes.

Answer (score 3):

you should use SQL Connection Pool feature for that.
It automatically manages in the background if a connection needs to be open or can be reused.
Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling?source=recommendations

Example copied from that page

> ```
> using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(  
>   "Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind"))  
>     {  
>         connection.Open();
>         // Pool A is created.  
>     }  
>   
> using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(  
>   "Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=pubs"))  
>     {  
>         connection.Open();
>         // Pool B is created because the connection strings differ.  
>     }  
>   
> using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(  
>   "Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind"))  
>     {  
>         connection.Open();
>         // The connection string matches pool A.  
>     }
> ```

By using the "using" statement, application checks if a connection in this pool can be reused before opening a new connection. So the overhead of opening and closing the connections disappears.

But after your last edit you seem to have other problems in your current architecture. Like the other poster recommends you can try to use the "with (nolock)" parameter in your sql statements. It creates dirty reads, but maybe that's ok for your application.

Alternatively if all your services use the same select statement maybe a stored procedure or a caching mechanism could help.

Comment: My ConnectionString is same accross all the services. So what is the behavior of thread pool?
how does this manage connection for each service?

Comment: If you are *copying* content from an external source you ***need*** to adhere[referencing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), which means your copied content **must** be in a blockquote.